# Python in Sublime text - No conditional test output

Tags: python, testing, conditional-statements, sublimetext3

I am running Sublime on a Mac, and I am new to Python 3. When I execute my code using "command + B", I usually see the normal output. However, when running *conditional tests* I cannot see the "True" or "False" response. How can I fix this problem?

Example:

```
car ='Audi'
car.lower() == 'audi'
```

I pressed "command + B", expecting:

```
 "True"
```

Unfortunately, I only get:

```
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You aren't printing anything based on your code. Assuming you're using the correct interpreter, use `print(car.lower() == 'audi' )`

Answer (score 1):

Use print

```
print(car.lower() == 'audi')
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like to avoid the print statement. If I run the same code on Python IDLE I get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't print without asking the program to print. In a python command shell it would print without the print line.

Is there any specific reason for you to not use the print statement?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am learning Python. The book I use shows conditional testing to illustrate their approach. I always want to understand to the best of my ability. I thought I didn't set up something right in sublime.

Comment: Maybe the book that you used a Python Shell for explanation. Try using Jupyter notebook or Python Shell directly which would help you follow the book. Happy learning!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime will not print True or False after being given a condition unless you explicitly tell it to print "True" or "False" after meeting your condition.

Comment: I should have phrased it differently. I just tested it out on Sublime Text 3 and you cannot view True or False unless you explicitly tell it to print "True" or "False" if the condition is met.